# Upload file to unique google drive account in android

Tags: android, google-drive-api, service-accounts

I need to build an application which upload the photo taken through the application to a unique google drive account.Have tried https://developers.google.com/drive/quickstart-android and build the app .But it is taking the google account which has been registered in the tablet,wheras i want to upload it to a unique account.Can someone help me on the same.

Answer (score 1):

You should use Service Accounts to store files on behalf of your application and not on a user’s Drive: https://developers.google.com/drive/service-accounts